# Validate aws credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

When a user input the aws secrete access key and access key id, System need to check are these valid credentials or not. Is there a way to validate aws user credentials.

Comment: You can simply make an API call using the credentials and see whether it returns an error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To verify whether credentials are *valid*, you can use the STS [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) API call. It will return information about the principal (user/role) that owns the credentials if they're valid, an error if they're not.

Even if credentials are valid, however, they might not have permissions to perform a particular API call. For that reason, it's always necessary to verify that individual SDK calls did not return an error.